# Get location / country from Facebook - Swift 2

Tags: ios, swift, facebook, facebook-graph-api, swift2

I'm having problems trying to get the user's country.
It was easy to get email, name, birthday, gender, hometown, etc... but when I try to get the user location I get nothing.

The code I'm using is:

Permisions:

```
loginManager.logInWithReadPermissions(["public_profile", "user_hometown", "user_location"], fromViewController: self)
```

The request:

```
FBSDKGraphRequest(graphPath: "me", parameters: ["fields":"location"]).startWithCompletionHandler({ (connection, result, error) -> Void in

                if error == nil{

                    print(result)
                    let location : NSDictionary! = result.valueForKey("location") as! NSDictionary
                    print(location)

                }else{
                    print(error)
                }
            })
```

The result of this request is: {id = 1083969718300950;}

I read about FBSDKGraphRequest with parameters: nil, but it doesn't work anymore.
Someone knows how to get the country nowdays?

Comment: have you set the user location in profile?

Comment: are you admin or tester of the app

Comment: I'm the admin, and like I said, got the other parameters like name, hometown, gender, etc. Location / country is the problem

Comment: Please check in graph explorer

Comment: In the graph explorer is the same. I get all except location. I did the next: me?fields=id,name,location,gender and I got: {
  "id": "192839182938912",
  "name": "XXXX XXX",
  "gender": "male"
}

Comment: Then you must check if you have set the location in the FB

Comment: I have set the location (I think so). http://i.imgur.com/gL6lUzH.png It's that?

Comment: Please check at your side

Comment: http://i.imgur.com/gL6lUzH.png is that ? I think the location is set.

Comment: how can I see this location is set or not from image?

Comment: Is from facebook, Valladolid is the city, and España is the country (Spain), so the location from facebook is set... you mean that?

Comment: have you linked that to your profile?

Comment: I don't get what do you mean. I can get all the info of that profile with my app, but I just want to get the country... and I cannot :(

Comment: Sorry bro I can not help to set the country in profile, try someone's profile

Comment: If you're positive that you have set up everything correctly, file a bug at https://developers.facebook.com/bugs